# Is it possible to change working directory and run php artisan command

Tags: bash, hosting, laravel-artisan, laravel-9, cron-task

I have setup a cron job to execute hello.sh

if I echo the current directory from the script using echo $PWD it
output /home/u341967117

```
echo $PWD
#output /home/u341967117
#and I can not run artisan command here since the Laravel installation for is /home/u341967117/domains/unieschools.com/public_html/ngit
```

so I try to change the directory before running the php artisan command

```
\#!/bin/bash
cd /domains/unieschools.com/public_html/ngit
echo $PWD
#php artisan command comes here
```

But output of the cron job executing the script is throwing error
[No such file or directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pd7Fq.jpg)

I tried changing the working directory to point to the laravel project folder but it keeps throwing error that no such directory exist

Comment: `/domains/unieschools.com/public_html/ngit` is not the same as `/home/u341967117/domains/unieschools.com/public_html/ngit` though

Comment: Yes, but the root folder is /home/u341967117

Comment: Then use `./domains/unieschools.com/public_html/ngit` or the complete path. `/` is the "topmost" folder in Linux. There's no `domains` folder underneath that "topmost" folder.

Comment: Do not post pictures of error messages. Put in the text.

Comment: @brombeer: It's a cronjob. Therefore it is better to specify the full path.

Comment: is it shared hosting?

Answer (score 1):

you can user this in you file:

```bash
PHP=`which php`

$PHP artisan optimize:clear
```